# Not possible to change margins on document?

Tags: formatting

So I am writing my thesis and the margins required are usually a bit different than default.

I have read multiple posts, most suggesting using something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
```

However, it does not work for me. Changing these parameters does not yield any change?

Nor does something like

```
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
```

yield any change...

EDIT: As per request here are more details on what I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}


\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{mwe}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fullpage,epsf}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{mwe}
\newcommand{\Mod}[1]{\ (\mathrm{mod}\ #1)}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bra{\langle}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket{\lvert}{\rangle}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1 
\delimsize\vert #2}
\newenvironment{indentLevel}[1]
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
```

Maybe some of these userpackages fix the margins which I can't overwrite?

Comment: If your entire document is `\listfiles \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\begin{document} hello world \end{document}`, what is the contents of your log file?

Comment: "does not work" is not anything we can debug. Provide an actual small complete test file (it should only need one line of text) that does not have the size you expect, and say what size you get and what you expected, and someone will correct your markup.

Comment: @Teepeemm see update.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle As I pointed out, "does not work" means does not change anything. Update available.

Comment: Sorry the update isn't that useful, it is far from minimal, it isn't complete it has no `\end{document}` so will make no pdf output at all, so we can not test the page size, and it generates errors `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \DeclarePairedDelimiter 
`

Comment: note in particular the error `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry.` if you load geometry multiple times with conflicting options, then the later calls just give an error and are not executed.

Comment: and naturally `\usepackage{fullpage` over-writes everything and resets the margins to be as small as possible.

Comment: Off topic: `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so the former is unnecessary.  The loading of packages would be better ordered in a more logical way, with packages relevant to the same goal entered nearer to one another.

Comment: You also have two `\documentclass` I assume the posted code isn't actually a document that you used locally and confirmed that it demonstrated the issue?

Answer (score 2):

The posted code generates multiple errors and generates no output however

the first call to `geometry` sets the page margin, the later call

`\usepackage{fullpage`

over-writes everything and resets the margins to be as small as possible.

The second call to `geometry` has conflicting options with the first so does nothing other than generate the error

`! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry`

So the end result is that you get the page size set by `fullpage`

If you remove the loading of `fullpage` and the second loading of `geometry` then the first will have an effect. (You should also remove both calls to `inputenc` and probably also `epsf`)